# Mysql Rollup with multiple group

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, rollup

Mytable with Id as autoincrement Customer, Date and Amount
I want to make a rollup that will sum the amount of every customer every day
I mean that the rollup is grouped by Date and Customer
This is what should my result look like :

```
+---------+--------------+--------------+------------+
| Id      | Date         | Customer     |     Amount |  
+---------+--------------+--------------+------------+
| 1       | 2017-09-19   |          B   |        10  | 
| 4       | 2017-09-19   |          B   |        15  | 
| 8       | 2017-09-19   |          B   |        02  | 
| 6       | 2017-09-19   |          B   |        18  |
| 5       | 2017-09-19   |          B   |        05  | 
| Total   | NULL         |          B   |        50  | 

| 9       | 2017-09-19   |         C    |        11  | 
|14       | 2017-09-19   |         C    |        10  |
| 12      | 2017-09-19   |         C    |        09  | 
| Total   | NULL         |         C    |        30  | 

| 11       | 2017-09-18  |         B    |         20 | 
| 15       | 2017-09-18  |         B    |         40 |
| Total    | NULL        |         B    |         60 | 

| 10       | 2017-09-18  |         A    |         1  | 
| 13       | 2017-09-18  |         A    |         1  | 
| 16       | 2017-09-18  |         A    |         1  | 
| 7        | 2017-09-18  |         A    |         1  |
| 3        | 2017-09-18  |         A    |         1  | 
| Total    | NULL        |         A    |         5  | 

| 2        | 2017-09-18   |         C   |        90  | 
| Total    | NULL         |         C   |        90  |
```

I tried :

```
Select
Mytable.Id,
Mytable. Date,
Mytable.Customer,
Mytable.Amount
From Mytable
GROUP BY Mytable. Date, Mytable.Customer WITH ROLLUP
```

But this does not work as expected .please help

Comment: Your query is invalid because the `Id` and `Amount` are not part of your aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

You need an aggregation.  Does this do what you want?

```
select t.Date, t.Customer,
       sum(t.Amount) as Amount
from Mytable t
group by t.Date, t.Customer with rollup;
```

If you actually really do want the `id`, then:

```
select t.id, t.Date, t.Customer,
       sum(t.Amount) as Amount
from Mytable t
group by t.id, t.Date, t.Customer with rollup;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff  but i tried your query and it does not work as my result on the table above

Answer (score 0):

I think below query will solve your problem.

```
SELECT IF(temp.date IS NULL, 'Total', temp.Id), temp.Date, temp.Customer, temp.Amount
FROM
     (Select group_concat(Mytable.Id),
             Mytable.Date,
             Mytable.Customer,
             SUM(Mytable.Amount)
      From Mytable
      GROUP BY Mytable. Date, Mytable.Customer WITH ROLLUP)) AS temp
```

Comment: Can I know version?

Comment: So, you have to enable the standard SQL behavior. Let me know you are getting an error or it's not giving your expected output.

Comment: I used as you told. I didn't use id in select clause.

Comment: Your format made it hard for me to see it. I edited your answer

Comment: thanks. I created a temp table to show 'Total'. I think it will give expected output.

Comment: @sagi  But i really need Id in the select clause

Comment: Then you need to use group_concat on id field. If you will not group_concat then it will return id of first one.

Comment: @Jack even with your query the result is not same with what i described above, please take a look and at my desired result table ..Thank you

Comment: @Yahia, can you share a result of above query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `id` column on `group by`

**For Version <= 5.7**

**Query:**

```
select 
    coalesce(id, 'Total') as id,
    date,
    customer,
    sum(amount) as amount
from
    mytable
group by date, customer, id with ROLLUP
having customer is not null;
```

**Result:**

> ```
> id    | date       | customer | amount
> :---- | :--------- | :------- | -----:
> 3     | 2017-09-18 | A        |      1
> 7     | 2017-09-18 | A        |      1
> 10    | 2017-09-18 | A        |      1
> 13    | 2017-09-18 | A        |      1
> 16    | 2017-09-18 | A        |      1
> Total | 2017-09-18 | A        |      5
> 11    | 2017-09-18 | B        |     20
> 15    | 2017-09-18 | B        |     40
> Total | 2017-09-18 | B        |     60
> 2     | 2017-09-18 | C        |     90
> Total | 2017-09-18 | C        |     90
> 1     | 2017-09-19 | B        |     10
> 4     | 2017-09-19 | B        |     15
> 5     | 2017-09-19 | B        |      5
> 6     | 2017-09-19 | B        |     18
> 8     | 2017-09-19 | B        |      2
> Total | 2017-09-19 | B        |     50
> 9     | 2017-09-19 | C        |     11
> 12    | 2017-09-19 | C        |      9
> 14    | 2017-09-19 | C        |     10
> Total | 2017-09-19 | C        |     30
> ```

---

**For Version > 5.7**

**Query:**

```
select 
    coalesce(id, 'Total') as id,
    date,
    customer,
    sum(amount) as amount
from
    mytable
group by date, customer, id with ROLLUP
having grouping(customer) = 0;
```

**Result:**

> ```
> id    | date       | customer | amount
> :---- | :--------- | :------- | -----:
> 3     | 2017-09-18 | A        |      1
> 7     | 2017-09-18 | A        |      1
> 10    | 2017-09-18 | A        |      1
> 13    | 2017-09-18 | A        |      1
> 16    | 2017-09-18 | A        |      1
> Total | 2017-09-18 | A        |      5
> 11    | 2017-09-18 | B        |     20
> 15    | 2017-09-18 | B        |     40
> Total | 2017-09-18 | B        |     60
> 2     | 2017-09-18 | C        |     90
> Total | 2017-09-18 | C        |     90
> 1     | 2017-09-19 | B        |     10
> 4     | 2017-09-19 | B        |     15
> 5     | 2017-09-19 | B        |      5
> 6     | 2017-09-19 | B        |     18
> 8     | 2017-09-19 | B        |      2
> Total | 2017-09-19 | B        |     50
> 9     | 2017-09-19 | C        |     11
> 12    | 2017-09-19 | C        |      9
> 14    | 2017-09-19 | C        |     10
> Total | 2017-09-19 | C        |     30
> ```

---

**Fiddle:**
*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=51d4fec7550a6318dadb262651082db5)*

**Note:** When using `group by` without **ERROR 1055** you need to set as

`SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));`